# android : Draw a clickable map

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener, ondraw

I would like to create an activity which displays a country map. I want to make every regions clickable.

[image]

I first tried to draw map with SVG data / javascript ( [see here](http://lab.proov.fr/carte_france_svg/demo.html)) and put it in a WebView. However, Vector Library is not available for most of android devices.

The best solution seems to pile up the images of regions (bitmap format ) and make them clickable, but I have no idea how to do.

Sorry to be rough in my explanations

Thank you !

Comment: What sort of functionality are you looking for? "Clickable" is very broad.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to get the id of the selected region and use it as extra in an intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it *overlapping* a **transparent grid** to the map. The grid is composed of 'touch sensitive' tiles. Tiles dimensions must be little enough to fill every region of your map. Every region will contain a certain number of tiles. You need to associate every group of tiles to the containing region. Then, at every tap on a tile, you are able to associate the correct region.

**EDIT**: example of Tile definition

```
public class MapView extends ViewGroup {

    // Tile definition
    //
    static enum Tile {

      T_00 (30, Region.region_a), T_01 (31, Region.region_a)
    , ...
    , T_328 (288, Region.region_h);

        private final int id;
        private final Rg region;

        Tile ( int id, Rg region ) {
            this.id = id;
            this.region = region;
        }

        public int getId() { return id; }
        public Rg  getRg() { return region; }

    }


// Implementation of MapView Class
...
```

**ps.:** the implementation described in my answer is just one of the possible implementation. You may create your own implementation depending on your needs.

Comment: Thank you. But depending of the resolution of the screen, position of tiles will be different, no ?  Do you have source code example ?

Comment: Yes I Have source code used in android application sold on Play Market. But I cannot post it to you. Solution of the problem you highlight is 'dynamic build of the User Interface' starting from screen resolution (both Map and Tiles must be re-arranged). It is a common programming problem.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. Can you just explain me in few words how to display the map. Do you use it as background of your gridView ? Do you put all your view in a frameView ? Thank you !

Comment: The Map is just a background image. You need to draw over the map a lot of tiles without display it (you may display it for debugging and to associate tiles to the correct region). I edited the answer to show the association.

Answer (score 1):

Make your map a subclass of SurfaceView to draw the map and override onTouchEvent() filtering for click's (x,y) coordinates.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have concrete examples or tutorials ?

Comment: @Canujohan: There is an android tutorial for SurfaceViews which provides all info, google it. When overriding onTouchEvent(), use a GestureDetector to recognize click, doubletap, scroll etc...